# HackerRank Seperate the Numbers Challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging, data-structures

**Hello everyone;**
I have been grappling with 3 cases that are not passing. The difference is so subtle with a digit change. I tried JavaScript notations for very large numbers or scientific notations but of of no avail.
The challenge is linked [here.](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/three-month-preparation-kit-separate-the-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=preparation-kits&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=three-month-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=three-month-week-four)

The different test cases are here.

console.log(separateNumbers("90071992547409929007199254740993")) //Gives NO although it should give "yes"

console.log(separateNumbers("90071992547401929007199254740193")) //Gives YES when 9 replaced with 1//

My code goes like:

```
function separateNumbers(s) {
var beautiful = true;
for (let len = 1; len < s.length; len++) { 
    var first = s.substr(0, len);
    var num = s.substr(0, len);
    if (s.length <= len) {
        continue;
    }
    var sNew = ''.concat(first.toString());
    while (sNew.length < s.length) {
        num++;
        sNew = sNew.concat(num.toString());
    }
    if (sNew === s) {
        console.log('YES ' + first);
        beautiful = false;
        continue;
    }
}
if (beautiful) {
    console.log('NO')
}
```

}

Your helps are very much appreciated. Thanks many

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your algorithm, it is working exactly as expected (and is right, btw).

The issue is with JS-Number data-type. The `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant has a value of `9007199254740991`. The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent integers between `-(2^53 - 1) and 2^53 - 1`

Instead of using std Number type, use BIGINT. That should give you correct answer for the test case.

Comment: Thanks so much Vish @vish4071;
This meant a lot for with which I have been grappling for quite some time. The secret was it. Here is the modification I made with your direction and boom. 




var first = BigInt(s.substr(0, len));
var num = BigInt(s.substr(0, len));

Comment: @bilalsarimeseli If you find the answer helpful, consider accepting it.